# Why is HttpUrlConnection not closing?

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

Why is this connection not closing. When it makes an initial connection, it then sends randomly like 1 or 2 subsequent request, or it might send empty strings like {}.

And the server isn't giving any response on purpose.

```
     private void playOnLoqooTv (String finalUrl) {
         HttpURLConnection con = null;
         try {

             URL url = new URL(finalUrl);

             // Log.d("TAG", url);
             System.out.println(url);
             //  Log.d("yo");
             con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
             readStream(con.getInputStream());
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }finally {
             if (con != null) {
                 con.disconnect();
             }
         }
    }

    private void readStream(InputStream in) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            reader.close();
        }catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connection stays on KeepAlive if you are checking if connection is alive somewhere in system it may appear that connection is opened because socket stays opened for a little bit longer than connection alone.

Comment: it is verified that it is connecting, but all i'm doing is trigging scripts but the connection stays alive. Basically pinging the server until I leave the activity

Comment: But it is finishing the reading and calling close? If yes then one option is that connection stays on KeepAlive if you are checking if connection is alive somwhere in system it may appear that connection is opened because socket stays opened for a little bit longer than connection alone.

Comment: Yes, your are correct and I am corrected. It is closing, because it isn't sending the data from the initial connection anymore just empty "pings". WoW! You just solved it. I'm using a remote logging lib that uses sockets and THAT! is what is keeping the connection alive. ok, thank you for your thoughts.